# Почему удается подключиться к контейнеру redis docker без переброски портов?

Tags: docker, redis, redis-server

Всем привет.
Запускаю:
`docker run --rm -it redis`
Контейнер имеет `ip: 172.18.0.2`
Потом на хосте подключаюсь к контейнеру:
`redis-cli -h 172.18.0.2`
И нормально подключается, все работает, ключи добавляются... Почему это происходит без переброски портов??? Сеть по дефолту- bridge

Comment: Потому что сеть по дефолту - bridge...

Comment: И? Я же подключаюсь снаружи, со стороны хоста...

Comment: Ну как раз дефолтная сеть и работает в пределах этого хоста.

Comment: Тогда смысл публикации портов. Вот к nginx такое подключение невозможно. То есть, если запустить docker run -it nginx, то на стороне хоста nginx будет недоступен, а redis доступен, почему?

Comment: Публикация портов делает их доступными при подключении из вне хоста.

Comment: Почему к nginx не подключиться тогда?

Comment: ¿А он действительно запускается и отвечает на запросы? ¿А какой адрес у контейнера? ¿А по какому порту он слушает? ¿А как вы проверяете возможность подключения? Заявления в духе "что-то не работает" следует подкреплять приводя [mcve].

Comment: docker run -it nginx не отвечает на хосте по адресу 127.0.0.1:80, если docker run -it -p 80:80, от отвечает. ip контейнера 172.18.0.2, ip интерфейса docker0 на хосте 172.18.0.1 В браузере вводим 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: docker run -it redis , ip контейнера 172.18.0.2 , запускаем на хосте redis-cli -h 172.18.0.2, то подключается и работает.. Why?

Comment: Ну так 127.0.0.1 это адрес хоста, а вы вводите адрес контейнера, по которому он виден с хоста - 172.18.0.1:80.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо ). Думал, что штатная сеть полностью изолирует контейнеры от хоста.